# Presto Query error for memory

Tags: presto

I am running complex query on Presto 0.148 on HDP 2.3 which errors out-

```
Query 20161215_175704_00035_tryh6 failed: Query exceeded local memory limit of 1GB
```

I am able to un simple queries without issues.

Configuration on coordinator and worker nodes-

```
http-server.http.port=9080
query.max-memory=50GB
query.max-memory-per-node=4GB
discovery.uri=http://host:9080
```

Query-

```
CREATE TABLE a.product_id, b.date, LOCATION FROM tblproduct a, day b WHERE b.date BETWEEN a.mfg_date AND  a.exp_date
```

I had to restart and then configuration was updated. I see Presto keeping query result set in memory if we have any operation performed on result set.
Hence Presto needs lot of Reserved Memory and default setting of 1 GB is not good enough.

Answer (score 5):

Make sure that you restart Presto after changing the config files, it seems like your configuration files are out of sync with the Presto server.